# Inconsistent records with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to use simple_html_dom and PHP to pick records from a page that are in the form: name/job/address. The problem is that not every record stores a value for 'job'. Say a page has 10 records, and only 2 of them record a person's job, then if I use something like the following:

```
foreach($html->find('span[class="name"]') as $e) {
    $name[]=$e->innertext;
}

foreach($html->find('span[class="job"]') as $e) {
    $job[]=$e->innertext;
}

foreach($html->find('span[class="address"]') as $e) {
    $address[]=$e->innertext;
}
```

then when I come to access the three arrays I find the $job array is only two records long, while names and addresses are 10 long, and so I don't know which of the 10 names those 2 jobs 'belong' to. Is there a way of keeping the arrays 'in step' with each other, or some other way of keeping records coherently intact here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then simply insert a null value when Job node is empty!!

```
foreach($html->find('span[class="job"]') as $e) {
    $value=$e->innertext;

    if (empty($value))
        $job[] = null;
    else
        $job[] = $value;
}
```

Or using the shorthand if-else version `$job[] = (empty($value) ? null : $value);`

Comment: Thanks Enissay. Your answer is a good one, but in practice these statements are in an enclosing loop cycling once through for each record. That means that $value will be set from the previous iteration. I could null it after each use, and in a roundabout way that's what I ended up doing. I set a $flag that gets set true if if we enter a foreach, and is tested immediately on exit, and if true, I assign "" to $job[]. Then I set $flag to false, and move on to look at the next field. Your answer is elegant but once you start to clear every $value after use I think it would end up as messy as mine.

Comment: Hi @Enissay. I think I'm happy with where it is. It's going to be a one-time use once it's working properly, so I don't have to worry about maintaining the code. Hence a little clumsiness in the code is tolerable and proportionate to my needs. Thank you for your support. I'd like to mark your answer as accepted, because given what you knew when you wrote it, it's fine! Thank you Enissay.